# How to give user rewards only if the user watched full video ad?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob, google-mobile-ads

I'm developing reward ad functionality in my app. I'm using `google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.5` package for showing ads. My reward is shown for the user even the user skip the video ad. I want to restrict the user from reward if they skip the ad.

This is my code snippet :

```
class AdsBloc extends ChangeNotifier{

  int _rewardedPoint = 0 ;
  int _preReward = -1;

  int getrewardpoint() => _rewardedPoint;
  int getpreRewardpoint() => _preReward;

  RewardedAd _rewardedAd;
  int _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;

  static initialization(){
    if(MobileAds.instance == null)
    {
      MobileAds.instance.initialize();
    }
  }

  void createRewardedAd() {
    RewardedAd.load(
        adUnitId: Config().admobRewardAdId,
        request: AdRequest(),
        rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) {
            print('$ad loaded.');
            _rewardedAd = ad;
            _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            print('RewardedAd failed to load: $error');
            _rewardedAd = null;
            _numRewardedLoadAttempts += 1;
            if (_numRewardedLoadAttempts <= 2) {
              createRewardedAd();
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void showRewardedAd(Future<dynamic> onEnd) {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show rewarded before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _rewardedAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
          print('ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.User dismissed');
        ad.dispose();
        createRewardedAd();
      },
      onAdWillDismissFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        print("pleasee dont");
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        createRewardedAd();
      },
      onAdImpression: (RewardedAd ad) => print('$ad impression occurred.'),
    );
    _rewardedAd.setImmersiveMode(true);
    _rewardedAd.show(onUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem reward) {
      _preReward = _rewardedPoint;
      _rewardedPoint += reward.amount;
      if(_preReward < _rewardedPoint){
        print("ad watched give them rewaard");
        // reward funcction
      }else{
        print("Please watch ad");
      }


      print('$ad with reward $RewardItem(${reward.amount}, ${reward.type}');
    });
    _rewardedAd = null;
  }

}
```

Above is my code. I don't exacly know where i'm made a mistake. I want to detect whether the user watch the ad or not. I want to reward them only if they watched the ad. How to do it. I'm confused.

Comment: What is the video player package you use to play video ?

Comment: I didn't use any video player package. It's video ad.